# Using If controller in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have trouble using If controller in Jmeter. Can someone help me with this?

Here is my question

**Can we use global parameters given in the CSV file as a condition in IF controller.**

For suppose I have username in CSV Data Set Set Config. Can I use like `$ {username} == "xyz"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use element [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for reading your usernames from the csv.
In "Variable Names" define the variable `username`

In the [If Controller](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) the variable needs to be quoted.

```
"${username}" == "xyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use more complex condition for [If controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie), like this:
${COUNT} < 10&&"${VAR}" == "abcd"

or the best one:
“${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}” - check if last sample succeeded